# Run a program in the background and then open another program using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

On the terminal, I have two programs to run using subprocess

First, I will call `./matrix-odas &` so the first program will run in the background and I can then type the second command. The first command will return some messages.

The second command `~/odas/bin/odaslive -vc ~/odas/config/odaslive/matrix_creator.cfg` will open the second program and it will keep running and keep printing out text. I'd like to use subprocess to open these programs and capture both outputs.

I have never used subprocess before and following tutorials, I am writing the script on Jupyter notebook (python 3.7) in order to see the output easily.

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(["./matrix-odas", "&"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, cwd=wd, universal_newlines=True)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print(stdout)
```

This is the code that i tried to open the first program. But Jupyter notebook always gets stuck at `p.communicate()` and I can't see the messages. Without running the first program in the background, I won't be able to get the command prompt after the messages are printed.

I would like to know what subprocess function should I use to solve this issue and which platform is better to test subprocess code. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this example at the end of [this section of the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)

```
with Popen(["ifconfig"], stdout=PIPE) as proc:
    log.write(proc.stdout.read())
```

it looks like you can access stdout (and I would assume stderr) from the object directly. I am not sure whether you need to use Popen as a context manager to access that property or not.

Comment: I tried this method but it seems like this is not the one to go. I ran the command on Jupyter with `&` and the cell block was just hanging. Since the first program has to be running in the background at all times, subprocress won't return messages on Jupyter unless I kill the program in the terminal.